# Create dynamic hash of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jquery so please bear with me. I need to create dynamic hash of arrays with the below structure

```
{
    "cricket_fields": ["aniket", "shivam" ],
    "soccer_fields": ["tiwari", "sandeep", "abhijeet" ]
    "football_fields": ["varun", "shikhar","naveen","sudheer","apaar"],

}
```

The problem with my code is Whenever

```
  var fields = {};
$.each( $(BUILDER.selected_field_items), function(key,value  ){
       fields[$(this).data('group')] =  [$(this).data('label')]  

    }); 

$(BUILDER.selected_field_items) =
[div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, div.field_items, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "#selected_fields_container div.field_items"]
```

And when iterating over this object I am finding keys with ($(this).data('group') ) and values with $(this).data('label')

```
div.field_items =

    "<div class="field_items" data-label="aniket" data-index="0" data-group="cricket_fields">Aniket    <span class="plus-icon action-icon">+</span>    <i class="icon-cross2 action-icon"></i>  </div>"
```

I have shown  data for the particular div.fields_items

Comment: what problem you are facing right now? what is `$(BUILDER.selected_field_items)`? untill we know what you have in `$(BUILDER.selected_field_items)` and what output you are currently getting,we can't help you

Comment: You can just assume I am getting keys as stated above. In the output, I am only getting last key and value. I am not getting the desired result as show above

Comment: try `fields[key][] = arr.push(value);`

Comment: Please note, array.push returns new length and not element. So `fields[key]` will hold `index + 1` essentially

Comment: Alive - Let me give it a try

Comment: Try `fields[key] = [value]`.

Comment: @ankur  what is `div.field_items`?

Comment: Alive - Updated my question once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `$(BUILDER.selected_field_items)` is, but this should achieve what you're trying to do:

```
if (key in fields) {
  // push `value` into the array if the key is found
  fields[key].push(value)
} else {
  // create an array with the first index set to `value` and set it to fields[key]
  fields[key] = [value]
}
```